# Web API Configruation file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to encrypt the connection string that is being given in the web.config file using aspnet_regiis.
So I am trying to open the aspnet_regiis.exe as

```
  aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/NewTestAPI" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

or

```
 aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/E:/Dropbox/NewTestAPI" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

It throws an error saying "Configruation file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object.Failed!" I tried even sharing the folder:

[image]

```
 aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/\\ABC\NewTestAPI" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

Even that throws the same error Configruation file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object.Failed!"

Below is the connectionStrings I have:

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ProConnection" connectionString="Data Source=J;User Id=T;Password=C;pooling=true;min pool size=5;Max Pool Size=60" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

I also tried giving the physical path of the site and also the site ID which is as shown in the picture but same error

[image]

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/E:\Dropbox\ABC\TestAPI" -site "3" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Initial answer**:

First you should make sure you grant access to an RSA encryption key with:

```
.\aspnet_regiis.exe -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "MySiteIdentity"
```

If you don't know what your site identity is, you can find it using `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`.

Then, if the web.config is under a different website than the DefaultWebsite, you'll probably need to specify the `-site` option. If that option is not specified, it defaults to `-site 1` (DefaultWebsite, which has the INSTANCE_ID server variable "1"). 
In order to find your site's INSTANCE_ID you can request the server variables in a `.cshtml` page like so:

```
    @foreach (string var in Request.ServerVariables)
    {
        Response.Write(var + " " + Request[var] + "<br>");
    }
```

Now, suppose you find that your site's instance id is 2. You can use that in your command like this:

```
.\aspnet_regiis.exe -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/NewTestAPI" -site "2"
```

*Note*: the "/NewTestAPI" path is a virtual path and assumes that your application is hosted in Local IIS as an application. Furthermore, the `-site` option is only necessary if your app is under a different website than the DefaultWebSite, or if you removed and created the DefaultWebsite again.

**Update**:
The actual problem is that the app was hosted in IIS as a website, not an application (so no virtual path, only a physical one). That's why aspnet_regiis would fail when trying to give it a virtual path (the `-app` option). To give aspnet_regiis a physical path we must use the `-pef` option like so:

```
.\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" "E:\DropBox\ABC\TestApi"
```

Comment: Can't we just give without the siteidentity or site instance.. Also I don't understand the virtual directory. I have created the website in IIS and linked path of the published application.. Should I be giving that path? This is my first application and I am kind of stuck..

Comment: What I did was I publish the project in to the File System and then created the website and linked the published application which is published inside the folder. And everything runs under IIS now

Comment: Ok, so just to double check: if you open IIS now you can see your application under 'Sites'? If you open `http://localhost/NewTestAPI` in a browser you can see your application working, right? If that's the case and the encryption still doesn't work, try specifying the -site option like I mentioned, using the "/NewTestAPI" path

Comment: I tried giving the site ID too but still it shows the same error . I have edited my question. With what I tried

Comment: I see what's wrong: you added your application in IIS as a *website*, not an *application* and you were trying to use aspnet_regiis as one would for an application (specifying the `-app` option). In your case you can simply use `.\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" "E:\Dropbox\ABC\TestAPI"`

Comment: I tried giving aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" "E:\Dropbox\ABC\TestAPI" -site "3" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"  It just list all the ASP.NET register action options

Comment: Notice that instead of `-pe` i used `-pef`, without `-site`.