# How to encrypt an Azure Devops Release Pipeline web config

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I currently have a release pipeline that uses a self hosted agent.  The agent does a web transformation on the config file and copies the files to an on-prem server.  The last step that I need to complete is to encrypt the connection strings in the web config file.

I have tried using a powershell script to encrypt, like I would do directly on the server:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/{app}" -site "{site}"

But get the following error:
The configuration for virtual path '/{app}' and site '{site}' cannot be opened.

Has anyone else run into this issue or found a different way of encrypting the connection strings in the release pipeline?

Answer (score 3):

After trying the script that Levi suggested, I tried with the other provider:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -pef
>   "connectionStrings" "{physical path to your website}" -prov
>   "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"

This worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when i didnot specify a correct value for `-site`. so you can check if the value you specified for `-site` is correct.

But when i made the `-site` value correct.  I got this error `A configuration file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object` .

I fix this by using a below script, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652010/web-api-configruation-file-cannot-be-created-for-the-requested-configuration-obj)

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "{physical path to your website}"
```

Comment: I have tried the -pef parameter as you suggested, but then get the following error: Failed to encrypt the section 'connectionStrings' using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: Object already exists.